# Why is ConsumerGroupCommand.main slow?

Tags: apache-kafka

I use `ConsumerGroupCommand.main(new String[]{"--bootstrap-server", bootstrapServers, "--group", groups, "--describe"});` to monitor the `lag` of `kafka`,But i find the code is very very very slow,sometimes it needs a few minutes?

My `kafka` cluster has 3 brokers,each `topic` has `50` partitions.

Comment: How do you measure the time? What does _very very very slow_ mean exactly? _Sometimes_? When has this been faster?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski,Thanks,I use a `main` function to execute `ConsumerGroupCommand.main`,Yestoday,once the `api`  cost 5 hours to return,In most cases,it needs 30 seconds. Is there other way to get the `lag` fast?